# Would the plot for my short story, "Bread earner in the family," be suitable for a play?

Tags: characters, plot, non-fiction, naming, dramatic-writing

I have a plot ready for the title "Bread earner in the family".

Genre: Family emotional drama.

It's a short story based on facts a non-fiction genre.

Summary:

How the bread earner in the family manages his household after the sole bread earner in the household is no more due to illness? The hardships, struggles made by him and his family.

Can a play in the auditorium be arranged for this story?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have at least one character, who wants something (goal) to satisfy a need they have (motivation), and they can't easily get that something or it won't actually satisfy their need (conflict), then you have everything needed to develop a story. As the author, the medium for sharing that story is your choice, whether it is as a short story, novel, novella, graphic novel, comic strip, tee-shirt, screenplay, interpretive dance, or live theater. Each medium has strengths and limitations, but all are constrained by the need to share a story.